# Input file is accused to be empty by CodeIgniter form_validation

Tags: codeigniter, validation, file-upload

I have an `input` for file uploading that has `required` rule, but even when selecting one, the framework accuses it to be empty and throws the error. Below is the rules:

```
$config = array(
    'registro_fisica' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'imagem',
            'label' => 'IMAGEM',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        ...
```

Below, the form:

```
<form action="/auto/usuario/add" method="POST" name="fisica_1" id="formulario_fisica_1" class="form_registro" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="tipo_usuario" value="F"/>
    <div class="p100">
        <div class="left">
            <span class="titulo">Dados Pessoais e Foto</span>
            <input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem"/>
            ...
```

That's it. Even I have chose a file, an error is thrown.

Comment: did you use codeigniter file up load http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: If you need to make it work with form validation use the call back feature with codeiginter form validation. And I find using form helper better http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart

Answer (score 0):

Required rule doesn't seem to work with files, use callback instead. Take a look at http://keighl.com/post/codeigniter-file-upload-validation/

Comment: My method is from `MY_Form_validation`. It seems it does not see the `$_FILES`

Comment: That's strange, not easy to tell why, we probably need you to show more code. You can try to add some var_dump($_FILES) in your controller method and in your library.